# How to install applications like helm on microk8s?

Tags: microk8s

In order to install applications like `helm` on Kubernetes on Google Cloud (gCloud) I start a cloud shell from the dashboard. How would one do that or install `helm` in a different way on microk8s?

I'm using microk8s 1.14 on Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `helm` is installed on the local Kubernetes cluster by using the command `helm init` and others locally. For specific installation instructions see https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#quickstart.

Comment: To ensure that helm found the expected files, I had to 

* alias microk8s.kubectl to kubectl

    snap alias microk8s.kubectl kubectl

* export the config

    microk8s.kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config

I used the snap version of Helm, and referred to the [microk8s user guide](https://microk8s.io/docs/)